# How to setup/initialize seed data for Azure Storage Emulator?

Tags: azure, testing, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-emulator

I am beginning to try to use Azure Storage Emulator for some integration testing.  I am testing a console application that reads data from Azure Table Storage and throws it into a database (a mocked db at this time).

As part of setup/arrange/initialize step, I would like to be able to populate my Emulator's local dev storage with some seed data without having to call our writing api's to write the data into emulated storage, since I am not trying to test that piece.

Is there any way to feed it a database file or something? I've worked on similar efforts in SQLLite and Cassandra Cluster Manager (CCM) that allow for this kind of seed data setup.

Comment: Where's this see data located? Is it in some kind of database or CSV files?

Comment: I can put it wherever, but I was thinking/hoping it could live as a csv or json file, next to the tests to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, data must be written into the emulator itself. There is no way to set it up with another sort of file. The emulator emulates the storage service as exactly as possible so for that reason needs to be accessed exactly as one would the real service.

Comment: Thanks Emilyl!  That's kinda what I figured.  My plan is to use the emulator as part of our integration testing plan.  I am going to work on creating a library to handle the setup and teardown of test data and all that jazz.  Client permitting, I will eventually try to publish the package on nuget and the source on github.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Using the emulator for integration testing is the perfect application of it. Do note that you should always run everything against Prod as well though since there are differences between it and the emulator. Is there anything else you need here for me to add to my answer?